# Laravel 8 db::rollback not working on none db/fatal errors or exception

Tags: database, laravel, exception, laravel-8, rollback

I am trying to create a record with `DB::beginTransaction` in a try catch so when any exception occurs it rollbacks the database transaction but it's not working.

I have tried to debug not getting what I'm doing wrong

```
DB::beginTransaction(); 
try {
     $customer = Customer::insert([
            'first_name' => 'firstname',
            'last_name' => 'lastname',
            'email' => 'user@email.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('password')
        ]);

// here I am echoing undefined variable to create error but it is not reverting the transaction
echo $j;
DB::commit();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
   DB::rollBack();
   throw $e;
}
```

Comment: I think `echo $j;` will not throw an exception. What PHP version are you using ? Try other things like `$j->something` so you get a real error, `$j` is not an object, hence it should go to the catch and rollback.

Comment: Or just do it manally: `throw new Exception('test my transaction');`